# javascript regex - add closing img tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to add a closing image tag. Current html:

```
<img class="logoEmail" src="/images/logoPDF.png">
```

What I want:

```
<img class="logoEmail" src="/images/logoPDF.png"/>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried Notepad? ;)

Comment: You may try, but this is not going to work failproof in all cases (like when there's a line break in the middle of the tag).

Comment: I need to use it in xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
myInput ='<img class="example1" src="/images/example1.png">';
myInput += '<img class="example2" src="/images/example2.png"/>';

result = myInput.replace(/(<img("[^"]*"|[^\/">])*)>/gi, "$1/>");
```

Explanation of the regex:

`<img` The start

`"[^"]*"` A string inside the tag. May contain the `/` character.

`[^\/">]` Anything else (not a string, not a `/` and not the end of the tag)

`>` The end of an IMG tag

This will only match unfinished tags, and will replace it by the whole thing, plus a `/>`

As I said before this is NOT bulletproof, probably there is no regex that would work 100%.

Comment: Why not just `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(<img[^>]+)/g, "$1 /");`? See my answer for the demo.

Comment: What if I want to do it for br tag also?

Comment: Basically repace "img" for "br"

Answer (score 4):

You could try this regex also,

```
result = myInput.replace(/^([^\.]*\.[^>]*)(.*)$/g, "$1/$2");
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oW0mB4)

It captures all the characters upto a literal dot and stored it into a group. Then it again captures characters upto `>` and stored into another group. Add a `/` in between the captured groups in the replacement part will give you the desired output.

Comment: Why not just `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(<img[^>]+)/g, "$1 /");`? See my answer for the demo.

Comment: It doesn't work for me as it puts double // in the case of the example2

Comment: @LatinSuD did the above comment for me?

Answer (score 0):

It can be as easy as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Demo Replace IMG tags w/ regex</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(<img[^>]+)/g, "$1 /");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <img src="images/logoPhone.jpg">
        <br>
    <img src="images/logoMail.png">
    <p>Some more text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

.
Explanation:

`<img`: match must start with this.
`[^>]`: after the starting match, the next character may be anything but >.
`+`: one or more occurances.
`g`: apply globally, do not return on the first match.
`$1`: as in the first capture group (= stuff between first set of parentheses).
.

Be aware that Firebug never shows closing slashes, regardless of doctype. But you can see the regex script in action here: http://regex101.com/r/zS2zO1.

Comment: It doesn't work for me as it puts double // in the case of the example2.

Comment: @LatinSuD - In your example that would indeed be the case, but the OP makes no mention of having image tags with and without closing slash. Only without.